# How to delete pixels from image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, transparency, pixel

I'd like to erase some single pixels of this image (the black ones):

[image]

But once I use the erase tool, I end up with somethings like this..

[image]

..which is not a pixel and its not "square", but a circle (even if I use a custom settings, in the top bar).

How can I achieve this using Adobe Illustrator CS6?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are [mixing concepts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80540). That is a vector image which does not use pixels. Deleting pixels is better done via Photoshop, but to fix your current situation:

- hit <kbd>A</kbd>
- click each black box and hit <kbd>DEL</kbd>